# How to find the minimum at each iteration?

Tags: iteration

I would like to iterate the table for {Q,0,3,1}, {R0,1,5,1}, the values of m=[3.83171, 7.01559, 10.1735, 13.3237, 16.4706, 19.6159, 22.7601, 25.9037] and calculate the corresponding k and Ra. Also, I want to indicate the minimum Ra for each value of R0. 
This is the code that I have written, but I don’t seem to get what I’m looking for.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
p = 2;
k[R0_, m_] := R0/m;
Ra[Q_, R0_, m_] := (Q*R0*p)/m;
data = Table[{Q, R0, m, k[R0, m], Ra[Q, R0, m]}, {Q, 1, 3, 1}, {R0, 1, 5, 1}, {m, 3.83171, 7.01559, 1}];
data // Flatten[#, 1] & // Grid;
TableForm[data,TableHeadings -> {{}, {},{}, {"Q", "R0", "m", "k", "Ra"}}]
```

I’m expecting the output to be something similar to this. Here I have shown the table for Q=1 as an example.
[image]

Comment: There is a missing comma: `{Q, 1, 3, 1} {R0, 1, 5, 1}?

Comment: Oh that was an error. I've edited it now. @DanielHuber

Comment: How can I run the code for m=[3.83171, 7.01559, 10.1735, 13.3237, 16.4706, 19.6159, 22.7601, 25.9037] and indicate the minimum value of Ra for each R0? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Ra depends on Q, R0, and m. You want the minimum relative to m. But what about Q?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How to iterate over specific values of m is well documented for Table: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html

But there are issues of data manipulation and display that might be worth explicating. So, here is our data:

```
data = 
  Table[
    {Q, R0, m, k[R0, m], Ra[Q, R0, m]}, 
    {Q, 1, 3, 1}, 
    {R0, 1, 5, 1}, 
    {m, {3.83171, 7.01559, 10.1735, 13.3237, 16.4706, 19.6159, 22.7601, 25.9037}}]
```

It looks like you want each indidual "cell" to be shown with table headers, so let's build a special function to do that (and we'll highlight the minimum cell while we're at it):

```
FormatCells[table_] :=
  With[
    {minPosition = OrderingBy[table, Last, 1]},
    MapAt[
      Item[#, Background -> Yellow] &,
      TableForm[{#}, TableDirections -> Row, TableHeadings -> {None, {"Q", "R0", "m", "k", "Ra"}}, TableSpacing -> {.8, .8}] & /@ table,
      minPosition]]
```

The `Item` won't mean anything outside of a `Grid` expression, but we'll use `Grid` to format the larger structure (with yet another special function).

```
FormatTable[table_] := Grid[FormatCells /@ table, Dividers -> All]
```

Now, we can get one "chunk" of data and display it:

```
FormatTable[data[[1]]]
```

[image]

**UPDATE**

For versions of Mathematica prior to 12, use this definition of `FormatCells` instead:

```
FormatCells[table_] :=
  With[
    {minPosition = Ordering[table, 1, Last[#1] < Last[#2] &]},
    MapAt[
      Item[#, Background -> Yellow] &, 
      TableForm[{#}, TableDirections -> Row, TableHeadings -> {None, {"Q", "R0", "m", "k", "Ra"}}, TableSpacing -> {.8, .8}] & /@ table, 
      minPosition]]
```

Comment: The first three code snippets work just fine in Mathematica (I am getting the output for the first and no output for the other two). But, the fourth code snippet gives me the following error: ________

MapAt   : Position specification OrderingBy[{{1,1,3.83171,k[1,3.83171],Ra[1,1,3.83171]}, ,<<4>>,1] in MapAt[#1&,{{{Q, 1}, {R0, 3},{m, 3.83171},{k, k[3,3.83171]},{Ra, Ra[1,3,3.83171]}},<<1>>] is not a machine-sized integer or a list of machine-sized integers. 

_____Note that I have not included the complete data in between the error due to character exceed. @lericr

Comment: Yes, sorry, that was a refactoring error as I was experimenting with the code. Try the updated version.

Comment: Oh, wait. You may have an additional problem. You still need to define `p`, `k`, and `Ra`. I just took them from your original post, and I didn't replicate them in my answer.

Comment: Oh got you!. But I still have the same error :(  ____MapAt::psl: Position specification OrderingBy[<<1>>] in MapAt[<<1>>] is not a machine-sized integer or a list of machine-sized integers. @lericr

Comment: What version of MMA are you using?

Comment: I'm using Wolfram Mathematica 11

Comment: Bummer. `OrderingBy` was introduced in version 12. Hold on, I'll try to think of an alternate.

Comment: Ohh! Yes please, that'd be very helpful.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: It works just perfectly now! There are two things I wanted to know. (1) What does ordering do? (2) And the command - FormatTable[data[[1]]]

Comment: Also, how can I extend the table for the other values of Q? i.e., Q=2 and 3

Comment: The "top" level in your `data` iterates over the `Q` values. I.e., `data[[1]]` gives us the sub-table for the first value of `Q`. `data[[2]]` would give the second, and so forth. So, to see the same sort of display for the second value of `Q` you'd execute `FormatTable[data[[2]]]`.

Comment: If you wanted to see all of these sub-tables in one display, you'd probably want to come up with a larger structure. You'd need to provide a description of how you want that display to look, and then I could make suggestions (this might be better as a new question).

Comment: As for what Ordering does, at this point it's best for you to read the documentation first. And as for `FormatTable`, I defined this as a new function, so you can see the implementation. If that's confusing you, then you need to get familiar with basic Mathematica programming techniques.

Comment: Oh, FormatTable[data[[]]] works so well for other values of Q!

Comment: What is more important for me, are the numerical values and indicating the minimum value. Thus the current display is perfect. I will definitely look into the documentation of “ordering” and “format table” commands for better understanding. Thank you so much! You’ve solved my problem. @lericr