# Assigning minimum position in a table

Tags: list-manipulation

I have three code blocks to perform the following tasks:

1. In the first block, I have defined the functions `k, eq1, eq2 and eq3`,
2. In the second block, the roots of `eq1, eq2 and eq3` are found by giving the values to the parameters `ε, R0 and m`,
3. The third block assigns the minimum position to the `Last` element of `data`.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
k[R0_, m_] := m/R0
eq1[ε_, R0_, m_] := 1 + α/6 + (1/360)*k[R0, m]*R*γ*ε; 
eq2[ε_, R0_, m_] := α + (1/6)*k[R0, m]*(-k[R0, m]^3 + 2*k[R0, m]*α+R*γ) + (1/12)*k[R0, m]*R*γ*ε; 
eq3[ε_, R0_, m_] := γ + (1/6)*k[R0, m]*(-1 + k[R0, m]*γ) + (1/120)*((-k[R0, m])*(k[R0, m]^2 + α) + k[R0, m]^4*α) - (k[R0, m]^2*R*α*ε)/20160; 

data = Table[FindRoot[{eq1[ε, R0, m], eq2[ε, R0, m], eq3[ε, R0, m]}, {{α, 0.5}, {γ, 0.5}, {R, 1000}}, AccuracyGoal -> 8, PrecisionGoal -> 8, WorkingPrecision -> 8], {ε, 0, 5, 1}, {R0, 1, 5, 1}, {m, {3.83171, 7.01559, 10.1735, 13.3237, 16.4706, 19.6159, 22.7601}}];

FormatCells[table_] := With[{minPosition = Ordering[table, 1, Last[#1] < Last[#2] &]}, MapAt[Item[#, Background -> Yellow] &, TableForm[{#}, TableDirections -> Row, TableHeadings -> {None, {"ε", "R0", "m", "k", "α", "γ", "R"}}, TableSpacing -> {.8, .8}] & /@ table, minPosition]]
FormatTable[table_] := Grid[FormatCells /@ table, Dividers -> All]
FormatTable[data[[1]]]
```

**Edit:** I wanted to highlight the minimum values of `R`. I have found the answer to this from one of my earlier questions: [How to find the minimum at each iteration?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/282191/how-to-find-the-minimum-at-each-iteration)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Part`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html), [`Values`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Values.html), and [`Min`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Min.html).

In `FormatCells` `table` is a list of sub-lists that contain lists of `Rule`s. So `Last` in your *ordering function* is acting on a sub-list of a list of rules. It returns the last list of rules in that sub-list.

What you want is to sort the between the sub-list by the smallest `R` value in a sub-list's list of rules.

Knowing that the ordering function is operating on the sub-lists that contain lists of rules you can create a new ordering function that uses `Part` to collect of all the `R` rules (in the last position of the list of rules). `Values` to extract the value from the rules. `Min` to calculate the minimum `R` in that list of rules.

```
ofunc = Min@Values[#1[[All, -1]]] < Min@Values[#2[[All, -1]]] &
```

Then the smallest position within each sub-list

```
Ordering[#, 1, ofunc] & /@ data
```

> ```
> {{2}, {4}, {4}, {4}, {3}, {5}}
> ```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you please put the complete code in a single cell. That will be very helpful for me

Comment: In your `FormatCells` replace `Last[#1] < Last[#2] &` with `Min@Values[#1[[All, -1]]] < Min@Values[#2[[All, -1]]] &`